# I want to ask about session in jsp

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

**index.jsp**

```
<form action="a.jsp" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="a">
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="admin">admin <input type="radio" name="b" value="member">member
    <input type="submit" value="c">
</form>
```

**a.jsp**

```
<% String a=request.getParameter("a"); String b=request.getParameter("b");

session.setAttribute("a",a); session.setAttribute("b",b);

response.sendRedirect("b.jsp"); %>
```

**b.jsp**

```
<%
String b = (String)session.getAttribute("b");
if(b!="")
{
    if(b.equals("admin"))
    {
        out.print(session.getAttribute("a"));
        out.print("this is admin");
    }
    else if(b.equals("member"))
    {
        out.print(session.getAttribute("a"));
        out.print("this is member");
    }
}
else
{
    out.print(session.getAttribute("a"));
    out.print("this is guest");
}

%>
<form action="d.jsp" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="d" />
</form>
```

**d.jsp**

```
<%
session.invalidate();
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
%>
```

The code is working fine, but if I don't choose the `admin` or `member` value, it should ideally go to guest condition in `b.jsp` page, but what I'm getting is an error at line 5.

**error**
An exception occurred processing JSP page /c/b.jsp at line 5

```
2: String b = (String)session.getAttribute("b");
3: if(b!="")
4: {
5:  if(b.equals("admin"))
6:  {
7:      out.print(session.getAttribute("a"));
8:      out.print("this is admin");
```

Comment: 1) What error are you getting exactly? Could it be a NullPointerException?  2) Do not use `!=` to compare Strings, use `!("".equals(b))`

Comment: You are new in JSP ? Then stop writing java code in you JSP, use servlets and send some data to the JSP. Then use the EL langage to create you dynamic content. Your code style is the old version of coding, this is not readable at all ;)

An you can use Filter Something class to check for each request if a session exist if not redirect to a page. This Filter is executed before the servlets. I will write an answer for this later if a foud some times ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `b.jsp` it appears that you are attempting to check the session map for an entry whose key is `b`, and then to decide what type of user is viewing the page based on that value.

The problematical code is the second line of the scriptlet in `b.jsp`:

```
if (b!="")
{
```

When there is no entry for `b` in the session map, this comparison should be `true`, causing the code which checks for admin or member to be executed.  This in turn will result in `b` being dereferenced in comparisons like `b.equals("admin")`, which will result in a `NullPointerException`.  Your intention I believe is to check whether there is *any* entry for `b` in the session map.  If no entry be found, then you will treat the user as a guest.  If there is no entry in the session for the key `b` then `null` will be returned, not empty string.  So you should be checking for `null`:

```
if (b != null)
{
```

Or, if you wanted to also treat an empty string value as being a guest, then you could try:

```
if (b != null && !b.equals(""))
{
```

Answer (score 0):

> Reason for Exception:
>
> Your b.jsp invokes nullPointerException if and only if the value for parameter is not set.

As you stated above, submission of form without selecting any radio button must be treated as Guest.

So here is 2 Solutions:

Solution 1:

> Instead of checking parameter as

`if(b!="")
{`

> Below code works fine, replace your b.jsp with this

```
<%
String b = (String)session.getAttribute("b");
if(b==null)
{
out.print(session.getAttribute("a"));
out.print("this is guest");
}
else  {
if(b.equals("admin"))
{
    out.print(session.getAttribute("a"));
    out.print("this is admin");
}
else if(b.equals("member"))
{
    out.print(session.getAttribute("a"));
    out.print("this is member");
}
}
%>
<form action="d.jsp" method="post">
 <input type="submit" value="d" />
</form>
```

Solution 2:

> Put Guest radio button also there in form, so that guest users will directly select "guest" Option. (here nullPointerException is avoided as always the value for parameter "b" will be set.)